# ¿Como mostrar registros entre dos fechas?

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito de su ayuda para formular una consulta que me permita mostrar los meses por año entre dos fechas. Tengo una tabla llamada adquisiciones donde guardo el `id_adquisicion` y `fecha_adquisicion`

Tabla Adquisición:

```
TBL ADQUISICIÓN
id_adquiscion
fecha_adquisicion
```

Necesito tomar la fecha de adquisición como fecha de inicio y pasarle otra fecha como fecha final y me traiga el mes de inicio y final de cada año, por ejemplo tengo una adquisicion como fecha de inicio el `2015-04-01` y como fecha final que yo le paso `2017-03-01` y me muestre los registro como en la siguiente tabla:

```
id_adquisicion | mes_inicio | mes_fin | anio
       1             4           12     2015
       1             1           12     2016
       1             1            3     2017
       2             5           12     2016
       2             1            3     2017
```

Comment: no crees que si la fecha fin está en duro en el primero de marzo, el mes fin siempre debiera ser marzo? Algo no me cuadra.

Comment: @amenadiel si, pero también necesito que me muestre los años que van pasando entre medio, hasta cumplir un año, necesito forzadamente esos valores para compararlos con otra tabla.

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer eso puedes utilziar la condición BETWEEN, no se si la base este en MySql, o Sql Server, pero sería algo muy parecido a:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    order_details 
WHERE 
    order_date BETWEEN CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Documentación:
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php

Saludos

Comment: Si tengo un evento el 2019-11-01 si me lo adjunta con la consulta pero si el evento lo tengo para el 2019-11-30 no me lo adjunta.

Answer (score 2):

El siguiente *query* te podría ayudar:

```
DECLARE @fecha_adquisicion_fin DATE;

SET @fecha_adquisicion_fin : = '20170301'

SELECT id_adquisicion
    ,MONTH(fecha_adquisicion) AS mes_inicio
    ,MONTH(fecha_adquisicion_fin) AS mes_fin
    ,YEAR(fecha_adquisicion)
FROM TBLADQUISICIÓN
WHERE fecha_adquisicion >= '20150401'
    AND fecha_adquisicion <= @fecha_adquisicion_fin
```

Comment: gracias, pero necesito que también me salgan los años que están en medio, por ejemplo si tengo como fecha de inicio `2015-04-01` y como fecha final le paso `2017-03-01`, en medio esta el año 2016 y necesito que me muestre ese valor tambien.

Answer (score 2):

**Esto va para largo**

Para esto vas a tener que generar una tabla que contenga todos los meses en el rango que quieres consultar. Lo bueno es que sólo tienes que generarla una vez. Por ejemplo

```
CREATE TABLE misfechas AS 
(SELECT DATE(20150101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150201) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150301) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150401) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150501) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150601) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150701) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150801) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20150901) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20151001) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20151101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20151201) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160201) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160301) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160401) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160501) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160601) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160701) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160801) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20160901) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20161001) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20161101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20161201) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170201) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170301) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170401) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170501) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170601) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170701) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170801) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20170901) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20171001) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20171101) AS fecha UNION ALL
SELECT DATE(20171201) AS fecha)
```

el contenido de la tabla sería

```
fecha
01.01.2015 00:00:00
01.02.2015 00:00:00
01.03.2015 00:00:00
01.04.2015 00:00:00
01.05.2015 00:00:00
01.06.2015 00:00:00
01.07.2015 00:00:00
01.08.2015 00:00:00
01.09.2015 00:00:00
01.10.2015 00:00:00
01.11.2015 00:00:00
01.12.2015 00:00:00
01.01.2016 00:00:00
01.02.2016 00:00:00
01.03.2016 00:00:00
01.04.2016 00:00:00
01.05.2016 00:00:00
01.06.2016 00:00:00
01.07.2016 00:00:00
01.08.2016 00:00:00
01.09.2016 00:00:00
01.10.2016 00:00:00
01.11.2016 00:00:00
01.12.2016 00:00:00
01.01.2017 00:00:00
01.02.2017 00:00:00
01.03.2017 00:00:00
01.04.2017 00:00:00
01.05.2017 00:00:00
01.06.2017 00:00:00
01.07.2017 00:00:00
01.08.2017 00:00:00
01.09.2017 00:00:00
01.10.2017 00:00:00
01.11.2017 00:00:00
01.12.2017 00:00:00
```

Ahora puedes consultar la tabla entre dos fechas con el formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, y de paso pedir el año y mes de cada fecha

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha) agno, MONTH(fecha) mes
FROM misfechas
WHERE fecha>= '2015-12-01' and fecha<='2017-01-01'
```

La salida de esto es:

```
agno    mes
2015    12
2016    1
2016    2
2016    3
2016    4
2016    5
2016    6
2016    7
2016    8
2016    9
2016    10
2016    11
2016    12
2017    1
```

Y por lo mismo puedes agrupar con esos campos (nótese que cambié las fechas para ser más ilustrativo)

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha) agno, MIN(MONTH(fecha)) mes_ini, MAX(MONTH(fecha)) mes_fin
FROM misfechas
WHERE fecha>= '2015-11-01' and fecha<='2017-02-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(fecha)
```

La salida es

```
agno    mes_ini mes_fin
2015    11  12
2016    1   12
2017    1   2
```

Esto tienes que envolverlo en un gran paréntesis y cruzarlo con tu tabla de adquisiciones. Lo que sí está claro es que la tabla que contiene todo el rango de fechas vas a tener que hacerla sí o sí, porque MySQL no tiene el tipo de generadores de filas que tienen Oracle o PostgreSQL. Y si quieres hacer tus queries con nivel de presición de días en vez de meses, vas a tener que generar todos los días fila por fila (te puedes ayudar con un excel).

Hay otra manera de hacerlo, usando una tabla dummy que tenga al menos tantas filas como días hay en tu intervalo, y una variable que se vaya incrementando un día a la vez, o un mes a la vez. Pero generar la tabla dummy te cuesta el mismo esfuerzo que generar la tabla de fechas, así que opté por darte la solución sin variables ni procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar y te cuento

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto un SP con mi solución, ojalá te sirva

```
BEGIN  
DECLARE Fda, xAno,xCuenta INT DEFAULT 0;  
DECLARE xLimI,xLimS,xId INTEGER;  
DECLARE  xFec date;

/*
  sin control de parámetros, pDesde y pHasta deberías chequearlos
*/       

DECLARE cur_reng cursor FOR
select 
    distinct `t`.`Id`,
    year(`t`.`fecha`)   
  from 
    `tu_tabla` `t` 
where t.`fecha` between pDesde and pHasta    
  order by 
    `t`.`Id`,year(`t`.`fecha`)   
 ;   

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET Fda = 1;

OPEN cur_reng;
-- 
FETCH cur_reng into xId,xAno;  
WHILE Fda = 0 DO  
    select min(x.fecha) into xFec
    from tu_tabla x       
    WHERE x.id = xId and year(x.fecha) = xAno;   

   SET xLimI= month(xFec);

    select MAX(x.fecha) into xFec
    from tu_tabla x       
    WHERE x.id = xId and year(x.fecha) = xAno 
    ;
    SET xLimS= month(xFec);

   insert into `resulta` (id,MesI,MesF,Ano)  
    values (xId,xLimI,xLimS,xAno);  
    FETCH cur_reng into xId,xAno;  

END WHILE;       

END
```